# intellij using wrong version of scala standard library

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project sbt repo.

I'm using sbt 1.3.8.

I wanted to use the `distinctBy` method (in my code, not in sbt) so I updated `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt` from `2.12.4` to `2.13.2`. I reimported sbt, but the `distinctBy` method was still not available. When I navigated to a different method in `Seq` it opened the file from the `2.12.10` scala-library, not `2.13.2`.

I tried deleting the coursier cache, all target folders, .idea folder, and then reimporting, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using **metals** instead of **Intellij**?

Answer (score 1):

sbt build definition is a Scala project in its own right found under `project/` directory. This Scala project is built using its own version of Scala separate from version of Scala the main project is build with. The `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt` controls the Scala version of the main (proper) project, and **not** the Scala version of the meta-project under `project/`. sbt 1.3.8 build definition projects are currently build with Scala 2.12 only, so only features within 2.12 are available.

Comment: I want to use distinctBy in my actual code, not in build.sbt

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Did you enable `use sbt shell`?